# Getting the Java jar file could not be launched even though it runs normally from terminal, any help?

Tags: terminal, java

I exported my Java project but when i try to double-click on it and open it normally I get that it could not be launched and I should check my console for possible error, found nothing there.
Tried launching it from my terminal and it runs fine there. 
what to do?

Comment: What is the name of the file you click on?

Comment: "test.jar" I named it test.

Comment: Is it a GUI program or stdout/in ?